# how to copy first 3 lines of all csv files in a folder into one file

Tags: python, csv, math

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
with open((filepath), 'w') as t:
    data = [(name), "scored", (str(score)) + "/10"]
    preader = csv.reader(t, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    pwriter = csv.writer(t, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',          quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
pwriter.writerow(data)
t.close()
```

This shows that the file in the location (filepath) now contains one score.
I want the program to copy the first 3 lines (3 newest scores) of all csv files in in directory E: and put them in one file.

How would I go about doing this?  Swift answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It takes time and effort to read, understand, and construct a response.  You can facilitate a quicker response by making it as easy as possible.  You should read and follow the guidelines specified here.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you.  I shortened the code to the relevant bit and clarified what I was asking.

Comment: Please review [How to ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a polite way of saying you have to invest a minimum amount of effort that is not evident here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `csv` module when you are dealing with a small part of the data.

```
import os
items_in_directory = os.listdir("E:/")
csv_files = [x for x in items_in_directory if x.endswith(".csv")]
# File to write to
f = open("file_out.txt", "a")

for csv_file in csv_files:
    with open(csv_file) as csv:
        for i, line in enumerate(csv):
            f.write(line.strip("\n"))
            if i == 2:
                f.write("\n")
                break
```